# Sounds in Java. Errors

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, audio

I am trying to play sounds in my game, for example when I press my UP key, to hear a laserfire sound but I get an error and I don't get why. Most likely I called the code wrong in my method or I got the source wrong.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class SpaceInvadersPanel$SoundEffect
at SpaceInvadersPanel$4.keyPressed(SpaceInvadersPanel.java:69)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

-

```
 import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;


public class SpaceInvadersPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Timer timer;
    private Player1 player1;
    private Player1weapon player1weapon;
    private Player2 player2;
    private Player2weapon player2weapon;
    public Image background;
    public ImageIcon bg;
    int width, height;

    public SpaceInvadersPanel() {
        bg = new ImageIcon("src/resources/BG.png");
        background = bg.getImage();
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {  
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (player1 != null && player2 != null) {
                    player1.updateForNewFrame();
                    player1weapon.updateForNewFrame();
                    player2.updateForNewFrame();
                    player2weapon.updateForNewFrame();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        };//end Actionlistener()

        timer = new Timer( 10, action );

        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                requestFocus();
            }
        } );

        addFocusListener( new FocusListener() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
                timer.start();
                repaint();
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
                timer.stop();
                repaint();
            }
        } );

        addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                int code = evt.getKeyCode();

                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    player1.centerX -= 10;
                }
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    player1.centerX += 10;
                }
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    if (!player1weapon.isFalling)
                        player1weapon.isFalling = true;
                    SoundEffect.SHOOT.play();
                }

                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                    player2.centerX -= 10;
                }
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                    player2.centerX += 10;
                }
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                    if (!player2weapon.isFalling)
                        player2weapon.isFalling = true;
                    SoundEffect.SHOOT.play();
                }
            }//end KeyPressed()
        } );//end KeyAdapter()
    }//end SpaceInvadersPanel


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(background,0,0,700,700,null);
            if (player1 == null && player2 == null) {
            width = 700;
            height = 700;
            player1 = new Player1();
            player2 = new Player2();
            player1weapon = new Player1weapon();
            player2weapon = new Player2weapon();
        }

        if (hasFocus())
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        else {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
            g.drawString("CLICK TO START THE GAME", 270, 350); 
            g.drawString("Player1", 550, 500); 
            g.drawString("Right arrow - Move Right", 550, 515); 
            g.drawString("Left arrow - Move Left", 550, 530);
            g.drawString("Up arrow - Fire", 550, 545);
            g.drawString("Player2", 50, 150); 
            g.drawString("D key - Move Right", 50, 165); 
            g.drawString("A key - Move Left", 50, 180);
            g.drawString("S key - Fire", 50, 195);
        }
        player1weapon.draw(g);
        player2weapon.draw(g);
        player1.draw(g);
        player2.draw(g);    

} // end paintComponent()

    public enum SoundEffect {
           SHOOT("sounds/Laser.wav");       // bullet

           // Nested class for specifying volume
           public static enum Volume {
              MUTE, LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH
           }

           public static Volume volume = Volume.LOW;

           // Each sound effect has its own clip, loaded with its own sound file.
           private Clip clip;

           // Constructor to construct each element of the enum with its own sound file.
           SoundEffect(String soundFileName) {
              try {
                 // Use URL (instead of File) to read from disk and JAR.
                 URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(soundFileName);
                 // Set up an audio input stream piped from the sound file.
                 AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
                 // Get a clip resource.
                 clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                 // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
                 clip.open(audioInputStream);
              } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }

           // Play or Re-play the sound effect from the beginning, by rewinding.
           public void play() {
              if (volume != Volume.MUTE) {
                 if (clip.isRunning())
                    clip.stop();   // Stop the player if it is still running
                 clip.setFramePosition(0); // rewind to the beginning
                 clip.start();     // Start playing
              }
           }

           // Optional static method to pre-load all the sound files.
           static void init() {
              values(); // calls the constructor for all the elements
           }
        }


    public class Player1{
        int centerX, centerY;
        int width, height;
        int explosionFrameNumber;
        int score = 0;
        boolean isExploding;
        public Image p1;
        public ImageIcon p1stock;
        public Image explodep1;
        public ImageIcon explodep1icon;

        Player1() {
            centerX = 500;
            centerY = 600;
            isExploding = false;
        }

        void updateForNewFrame() {
            if (isExploding) {
                    explosionFrameNumber++;
                    if (explosionFrameNumber == 15) {
                        width = 700;
                        centerX = (int)(width*Math.random());
                        centerY = 600;
                        isExploding = false;
                    }
                }
            if(centerX <= -30)
                centerX = -10;
            else if(centerX > 640)
                centerX = 630;
        }//end updateForNewFrame

        void draw(Graphics g) {
            p1stock = new ImageIcon("src/resources/player1.png");
            p1 = p1stock.getImage();
            explodep1icon = new ImageIcon("src/resources/explosion.png");
            explodep1 = explodep1icon.getImage();  
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawString("Score: " + score, 20, 450);
            g.drawImage(p1, centerX, centerY, p1.getWidth(null), p1.getHeight(null),null);
            if (isExploding) {
                g.drawImage(explodep1, centerX - 4*explosionFrameNumber + 40, centerY - 2*explosionFrameNumber + 10, 
                            8*explosionFrameNumber, 4*explosionFrameNumber,null);
            }
        }//end draw()

    }//end Player1


    public class Player2{
        int centerX, centerY;
        int width, height;
        boolean isExploding;
        int explosionFrameNumber;
        int score = 0;
        public Image p2;
        public Image explodep2;
        public ImageIcon p2stock;
        public ImageIcon explodep2icon;

        Player2() {
            centerX = 50;
            centerY = 30;
            isExploding = false;
        }

        void updateForNewFrame() {
            if (isExploding) {
                explosionFrameNumber++;
                if (explosionFrameNumber == 15) {
                    isExploding = false;
                    width = 700;
                    centerX = (int)(width*Math.random());
                    centerY = 30;
                }
            }
            if(centerX <= -30)
                centerX = -10;
            else if(centerX > 640)
                centerX = 630;
        }//end updateForNewFrame()

        void draw(Graphics g) {
            p2stock = new ImageIcon("src/resources/player2.png");
            p2 = p2stock.getImage();
            explodep2icon = new ImageIcon("src/resources/explosion.png");
            explodep2 = explodep2icon.getImage();
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawString("Score: " + (score), 20, 250);
            g.drawImage(p2, centerX, centerY, p2.getWidth(null), p2.getHeight(null),null);
            if (isExploding) {
                g.drawImage(explodep2, centerX - 4*explosionFrameNumber + 40, centerY - 2*explosionFrameNumber + 10, 
                            8*explosionFrameNumber, 4*explosionFrameNumber,null);
            }
        }//end draw()

    } //end Player2


    public class Player1weapon{
        int centerX, centerY;
        boolean isFalling;
        public Image laserp1;
        public ImageIcon lp1icon;


        public Player1weapon() {
            isFalling = false;
        }

        void updateForNewFrame() {
            if (isFalling) {
                if (centerY < player2.centerY - 50) {
                    isFalling = false;
                }
                else 
                    if (Math.abs(centerX - player2.centerX - 40) <= 30 && Math.abs(centerY - player2.centerY + 35) <= 70) {
                        player2.isExploding = true;
                        player2.explosionFrameNumber = 1;
                        isFalling = false;
                        player1.score+=10;
                    }
                    else
                        centerY -= 20;
            }//end if  
        }//end updateForNewFrame()

        void draw(Graphics g) {
            lp1icon = new ImageIcon("src/resources/laserplayer1.png");
            laserp1 = lp1icon.getImage();
            if (!isFalling) {
                centerX = player1.centerX + 37;
                centerY = player1.centerY + 23;
            }
            g.drawImage(laserp1, centerX, centerY - 8, laserp1.getWidth(null), laserp1.getHeight(null),null);
        }//end Draw()

    }//end player1weapon


    public class Player2weapon{
            int centerX, centerY;
            boolean isFalling;
            public Image laserp2;
            public ImageIcon lp2icon;

            public Player2weapon() {
                isFalling = false;
            }

            void updateForNewFrame() {
                if (isFalling) {
                    if (centerY > player1.centerY + 50) {
                        isFalling = false;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (Math.abs(centerX - player1.centerX) <= 20 && Math.abs(centerY - player1.centerY + 20) <= 20) {
                            player1.isExploding = true;
                            player1.explosionFrameNumber = 1;
                            isFalling = false;
                            player2.score+=10;
                        }
                        else
                            centerY += 20;
                }//end if   
            }//end updateForNewFrame()

            void draw(Graphics g) {
                lp2icon = new ImageIcon("src/resources/laserplayer2.png");
                laserp2 = lp2icon.getImage();
                if (!isFalling) {
                    centerX = player2.centerX + 1;
                    centerY = player2.centerY + 15;
                }
                if (isFalling) {
                    g.drawImage(laserp2, centerX + 36, centerY - 8, laserp2.getWidth(null), laserp2.getHeight(null),null);
                }
            }//end Draw()

        }//end player2weapon


    /*public class Asteroid{
        int centerX, centerY;
        boolean isFalling;
        public Image asteroid;
        public ImageIcon icon;

        public Asteroid() {
            isFalling = false;
            icon = new ImageIcon("src/resources/laserplayer2.png");
            asteroid = icon.getImage();
        }

        void updateForNewFrame() {
            if (isFalling) {
                if (centerY > player1.centerY + 50) {
                    isFalling = false;
                }
                else 
                    if (Math.abs(centerX - player1.centerX) <= 20 && Math.abs(centerY - player1.centerY + 20) <= 20) {
                        player1.isExploding = true;
                        player1.explosionFrameNumber = 1;
                        isFalling = false;
                        player2.score+=10;
                    }
                    else
                        centerY += 50;
            }//end if   
        }//end updateForNewFrame()

        void draw(Graphics g) {
            if (!isFalling) {
                centerX = player2.centerX + 1;
                centerY = player2.centerY + 15;
                g.drawImage(asteroid, centerX + 36, centerY - 8, asteroid.getWidth(null), asteroid.getHeight(null),null);
            }
            if (isFalling) {
                g.drawImage(asteroid, centerX + 36, centerY - 8, asteroid.getWidth(null), asteroid.getHeight(null),null);
            }
        }//end Draw()

    }//end asteroid*/

}//end SpaceInvadersPanel
```

Comment: Most likely, so could you include your code, please? It’s an important part of any question :)

Comment: I see a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, please check the javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html. Maybe you did not include all required libraries into the classpath.

Comment: Do you see SpaceInvadersPanel$SoundEffect class file in output folder and are you sure that its path is under the classpath ?

Comment: @hgupta Can you elaborate?

Comment: @home I am not quite sure what library I missed..

Comment: The Javadocs for that error are misleading. The real problem is that the SoundEffect enum did not initialise correctly. Do you have any other stack traces or errors in the output of your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace points that a class wasn't initialized when the program tried to access it during runtime. In such a scenario, there should be an `ExceptionInInitializerError` as well in the stacktrace. If yes, you may put an Exception or Throwable block in `SoundEffect` constructor to see what exactly is going wrong :

```
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For further doubts, you can go through this - [Debugging a NoClassDefFoundError](http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html)